# Loading a JS file from a CDN, how to prevent browser caching?

Tags: javascript, cdn

Every few hours (or less it depends) I will be updating a javascript file that will contain a JSON object that contains notifications that will appear on the website.  This JSON object is what I will be updating periodically and so it cannot be cached by browsers.

The javascript will be hosted on a CDN, and this file will be on client websites like:

```
<script src="//example.com/1.7.1/my_file.js"></script>
```

How can I possible prevent browser caching in this type of situation?

I guess the best way would be for all clients to have the same javascript file, and then make an ajax request to pull down the messages?  This way the "my_file.js" can be cached, but the ajax response will not be.

Comment: You can add a timestamp at the end of your url...

Comment: @brso05 you should put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a timestamp after the path my_file.js?time=currentTime

To keep the HTML clean you can add something like this in another local js file

```js
$("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath?time=' + Date.now() + '"></script>');
```

Or you can use $.getScript, requirejs, etc.

Comment: It doesn't even need to be a timestamp. As soon as any GET parameter changes, the cached version is discarded. jQuery uses `&_=<timestamp>` if you use `$.ajax()` with the option `cache: false`. Font-awesome uses the parameter `v=4.5.0`. StackOverflow adds a `v=<hash>` to each file

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what CDN you use and the features available. Some approaches:

- Instruct the CDN to cache the file for around an hour, so it'll automatically fetch a new one every hour (assuming someone is requesting). This means that users won't necessarily get the change immediately, but would be within half an hour of you changing
- Along with that, Have the CDN send the end users a "no-cache" Cache-Control header. Depending on the CDN, this would simply be what your origin sends and you use some an override on the CDN (or one of the various means of instructing the CDN to cache it via headers, such as Surrogate-Cache-Control)
- Alternatively, the above-mentioned versioning/timestamped URL. The downside of this is that it requires you to update any references to your file to include the version id. If your pages are auto-generated this is fine.
- Allow the CDN to cache the file indefinitely, but make use of a "purge" or "invalidation" feature to force the CDN to request the new version the next time it is requested. This would mainly apply if you would have a reason to have the file not update for more than a few hours or a day.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is an obvious thing but I'll state it anyway: If a CDN is used and it has a purge option, like all CDNs should have, then using "no-cache" is a good way (depending on your site and users' networks), which is the opposite of asking the browser to cache for months / years / permanently. A CDN changes the approach to caching entirely because it is supposed to be fast, and everywhere (many PoPs), which makes "no-cache" fine for some use-cases.